# Object "i' not found within an R for loop (k-fold cross validation)

Tags: r, k-fold

Like the title says, I am trying to do k-fold cross validation. My coding skills are very basic, please explain as simply as possible.

```
    library(ISLR)
    install.packages("ISLR")
    library(ISLR)
    install.packages("boot")
    library(boot)

    data <- attach(read.csv("TutWk7Data-1.csv",header=TRUE))

    MSE = NULL

    for (i in 1:7){
      model = glm(Y~poly(X,i),data=data)
      MSE[i] = cv.glm(data,model,K=10)$delta[1]
    }
```

I get this error

```
Error in poly(X,i):object "i" not found
```

Comment: Try re-running the command ```attach(data)```after ```MSE = NULL```, & then run your loop. Does this work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post a sample of your data (by copying/pasting the output of `dput(data )` for example) or create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code works well with the in-built dataset `mtcars`, so it is not possible to reproduce your error

Comment: The following objects are masked from data (pos = 3):

    X, Y

The following objects are masked from read.csv("TutWk7Data-1.csv", header = TRUE) (pos = 4):

    X, Y

The following objects are masked from data (pos = 5):

    X, Y

The following objects are masked from read.csv("TutWk7Data-1.csv", header = TRUE) (pos = 6):

    X, Y

The following objects are masked from read.csv("TutWk7Data-1.csv", header = TRUE) (pos = 7):

    X,Y ...@Andy this is what i get after running the attach(data) line but in the end I do get my 7 mse... should I be worried ?  @Elia thank

Comment: also why do i get  7 mean square errors... should it not be (10x7) since every model has k=10 and I am modeling 7 models...or does r automatically show me the smallest mse for each of the seven models?

Comment: What is `attach` good for if you actually want to read data from a file? `attach` does not even return a data.frame, so `data` does not contian the data from the file. remove the call to `attach` and see if this solves your issue.